# Cannot Change Font in Firefox Only

Tags: css, fonts

One of the weirdest CSS issues I've seen. The .product-bottom and .product-title classes have the `font-family: Roboto`. This displays fine in IE and Chrome. Inspecting the elements in Firefox, the font is apparently used on the element and is successfully used throughout the site in other elements.

Editing the font-family attributes when inspecting the element has no affect on it. The computed css values show `!important` is not used. When used in the inspector on font-family, it has no affect. There are no jQuery or CSS errors, though there are plenty of CSS warnings.

The site is [removed after fix].

Screenshot of the font issue in FF. Problem text is: "Grey Hair Color Body Wave Human Hair Weave"

[image: Screenshot of the font issue in FF.]

Comment: Rather than a link to your website, please provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable

```
.product-title {
  text-transform: full-width;
}
```

and it looks fine. The full-width value is only experimental and mainly supposed to be used with square letters like in Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation of full-width.

Answer (score 1):

Replease this css:

```
.product-title {
  text-transform: full-width;
}
```

with this:

```
.product-title {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```